# Threading in Python - Have Researched and cant find answer

Tags: python, multithreading, port

I have the following script which just isnt working for me :(.  I essentially want to create 10 threads to port scan a range of 100 ports.  It should seem simple but I dont know where I am going wrong.  Im new to python and have been looking at how to get this working for the past two weeks and I know give up. When executed it just does nothing.  Help please :).

EDIT: Updated the code but it now states none when I run it.
                #Import Modules
                from scapy.all import *
                from Queue import Queue
                from threading import Thread

```
            #Set Variables
            threadCount = 10
            destIP = "192.168.136.131"
            portLength = 100
            q = Queue(maxsize=0)

            #Empty Arrays
            openPorts = []
            closedPorts = []
            threads = []

            def qProcessor(q):
                while True:
                        try:
                            print q.get()
                            #getQ = q.get()
                            #getQ()
                            #if getQ() is None:
                            #   break 
                            #else:
                            q.task_done()
                        except Exception as e:
                            print 'error in qprocessor function'
                            print e


            def portScan(port, dstIP):
                scan = sr1(IP(dst=dstIP)/TCP(dport=port,flags="S"), verbose=0)
                if scan.getlayer(TCP).flags == 0x12:
                    openPorts.append("IP: %s \t Port: %s"%(scan.getlayer(IP).src, scan.getlayer(TCP).sport))
                    sr1(IP(dst=dstIP)/TCP(dport=port,flags="R"),verbose=0)

                if scan.getlayer(TCP).flags == 0x14:
                    closedPorts.append("IP: %s \t Port: %s"%(scan.getlayer(IP).src, scan.getlayer(TCP).sport))


            def main():

                try:
                        for i in range(threadCount):
                                worker = Thread(target=qProcessor, args =(q,))
                                worker.setDaemon(True)
                                worker.start()
                except Exception as e:
                        print "error in worker section"
                        print e


                for p in range(portLength):
                    q.put(portScan(p, destIP))

                q.join()
            if __name__ == '__main__':
                main()

            for port in openPorts:
                print port
```

So i found the answer.  This has killed me for two weeks and I ended up debugging the application with the pdb module and the '-v' switch.  I have learnt a lot from this exercise and want to kill python after this lol.  But working it out with the little hints from stackoverflow has been awesome.  Here is the final script.  I have commented the line that was giving me issues whilst I work out a way around it.  BTW this works fine without threading.

```
            #Import Modules
            from scapy.all import *
            from Queue import Queue
            from threading import Thread

            #Set Variables
            threadCount = 10
            destIP = "192.168.136.131"
            portLength = 100
            q = Queue(maxsize=0)


            #Empty Arrays
            openPorts = []
            closedPorts = []
            threads = []

            def main():
                    try:
                            for i in range(threadCount):
                                    worker = Thread(target=qProcessor, args =(q,))
                                    worker.setDaemon(True)
                                    worker.start()
                    except Exception as e:
                            print "error in worker section"
                            print e


                    for p in range(portLength):
                            q.put(portScan(p, destIP))

                    q.join()

            def qProcessor(q):
                while True:
                        try:
                            q.get()
                            q.task_done()
                        except Exception as e:
                            print 'error in qprocessor function'
                            print e


            def portScan(port, dstIP):
                scan = sr1(IP(dst=dstIP)/TCP(dport=port,flags="S"), verbose=0)
                if scan.getlayer(TCP).flags == 0x12:
                    openPorts.append("IP: %s \t Port: %s"%(scan.getlayer(IP).src, scan.getlayer(TCP).sport))
                #   sr1(IP(dst=dstIP)/TCP(dport=port,flags="R"),verbose=0)

                if scan.getlayer(TCP).flags == 0x14:
                    closedPorts.append("IP: %s \t Port: %s"%(scan.getlayer(IP).src, scan.getlayer(TCP).sport))
                else:
                    pass

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                main()

            for port in openPorts:
                print port
```

Comment: Have you tried debug it or put some prints?

Comment: Just did it and it states threads can only be started at once

Comment: Note: i put the exception in the main function.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to pass the object `Scan` to your threads and not `portScan`?

Not being familiar with the full contents of the `scapy`module, it is considered bad form to do

```
from scapy.all import *
```

especially if you only need one or two classes/functions from it. It would lead to namespace pollution. Same thing goes for `threading` from which you only needed Thread.
Anyway, I'm surprised the python interpreter doesn't raise an error, because I don't see `Scan` listed in the [scapy API](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html) (and this is why I make the remark of not doing `from moduleX import *` - someone else might need to track where `Scan` comes from). See what happens when you pass your self-defined function `portScan` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are several advises I can give to you. 
The first one is actually that you should not use python for purposes of port scanning. In most of official linux repositories there is a tool made by professionals called NMap. By using this tool you can solve your problem easily.

Another advise is on how you can use threading if you are still looking forward to write your own code. You can use the **multithread-callback** scheme. Callback is a function that every thread should call after distribution between threads is done.

For example: you can put all pairs (port, callback) into queue and then by another function  called worker you pop this pair from queue and call the while True: callback(port).

The most import part is creation of workers. It goes like this:

```
for i in threads_num:
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hi PaulCher,

Do you have any links I can go to to see how this works. Yeah I use NMAP quite a bit but I want to learn how to use python and write scripts.  This has been the only one that has stumped me so far.

Comment: For sure, the best description of this scheme I found on [this site](http://pymotw.com/2/threading/)

Comment: Good site but my issue is that I want to specify the amount of threads. I am stumped on how to add 100 tasks let's say and create ten threads to do the work.

Comment: Create threading using for-cycle like in "Subclassing Thread" paragraph. You can add tasks as I said using Queue. Adding every task to queue and then each worker will use get method to gather the next task. "get" method should have no problems, cuz this operation is atomic.

Comment: So I have gotten a little closer but now getting none with the above code.

Comment: So after all this time I found out what was holding up my script.  I feel like crying and swearing at the same time.... ARRRRRR it was the reset packet on the syn.  I have put my final code up to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Answer above.  The issue was with the reset packet holding up the script.